# How to apply showPanel:boolean property to matautocomplete as shown in documentation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use autocomplete property

> showPanel: boolean Whether the autocomplete panel should be visible,
> depending on option length.

From documentation I understand, autocomplete panel will extend its width depending on mat options length. Please correct me If I am wrong. Link to offcial documentation [offcial documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api)

I have one mat option which is very long in length and even after applying showPanel; matpanel has not expanded. I am not sure whether I am using the property correctly. Here is what I have tried

**template.html**

```
<label>Search names</label>
<input type="text"
       placeholder="search name"
       aria-label="Number"
       matInput
       [formControl]="myControl"
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
     
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" showPanelLocal>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**template.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matautocom',
  templateUrl: './matautocom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matautocom.component.css']
})
export class MatautocomComponent implements OnInit {

  names: string[] = ['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry', 'ustu', 'caty','momo', 'rekh', 'john', 'kemp'];

  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined;

  @Input('showPanel') showPanelLocal: boolean = true;//showPanel property
 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
 
    return this.names.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
   
  }

}
```

As you see in the picture mat option is not completely visible.
Here is the link to angular documentation.

[image]

Comment: I have added stackblitz,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xv76an?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it wrong, sadly. This is NOT an input so it can't be set - it's just a property that informs whether the dropdown will be visible. It's based on the length of the options, i.e. if there are 0 options (e.g. user types something that is not part of any provided options) this will return false. You can find the source code for this property [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/fbb80fcaad09ea22cb75c1a67382e98bb29ab631/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L109), and it's value is set [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/fbb80fcaad09ea22cb75c1a67382e98bb29ab631/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L245) - so updating it manually will make no difference.

You can set the width of the dropdown panel by setting the `panelWidth` property (docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete)) on your autocomplete. The reasoning for this being a static value is that otherwise the dropdown would change width based on the currently rendered options, which would be terrible UI (as the width could change after every typed character).

Other than that, you can either change the override the styling of the panel and items, but personally I would advise against that.